# window.location.href doesn't work on Ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, canvas, window.location

Hi I download a canvas with the following codes locally, however it doesn't work on Ipad. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks.

```
 var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
 window.location.href=img;
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to force a (local) download, but iOS Safari does not allow downloads.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS doesn't allow forced direct octet stream downloading of images in this way. You have to strip off the mime type in that circumstance and ask the user to save it manually (press + hold, save).

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
window.location.href=img;
```

Add a little iOS regex maybe too for the useragent, so it works natively on other devices.